# Can the stalker attack in TheDAO be stopped?

Tags: security, the-dao, attacks

https://github.com/slockit/dao/wiki/Why-The-Stalker-attack-is-a-non-issue#a-way-to-guarantee-you-get-your-eth says:

> Assuming the attacker also voted yes in all of the new Curator
>   Proposals, in the last possible block move the DAO tokens from you
>   main account to one of the 10 other accounts (choose a random one) and
>   call splitDAO().

What does **"in the last possible block"** mean?  How is this a "guarantee you get your ETH" when [a transaction can't be forced in a particular block](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/4581/42)?

Comment: Your 'guaranteed' link points to the topic *last transaction in a block*, while the citation argues about *last block in DAO creation*. These two things do not fit together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: The idea is to move all your tokens to a random split in the last possible block within the 1 week debating period. The attacker could only guess.

PROBLEM: You are right, there is no guarantee that miners will mine your transaction at the last block. This is a rather unelegant solution.

How does a split work:

1. create a proposal with `newCurator=true`, `recipient=<new curator address>`
2. You (and the attacker) vote in favor of the proposal
3. At least 1 week debating period in which a token holder can call `splitDAO`

See [How to Split the DAO](https://github.com/slockit/DAO/wiki/How-to-split-the-DAO)

So what Christopher Jentzsch is proposing is that with enough accounts and enough proposed splits, you can move your tokens in the last block before debating period has ended. This is not guaranteed as the miner can not be coerced to mine your transaction right in that block.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that you will get it in any given block. But given that you get infinity attempts there it is a guarantee that you will get it in a last block.

If it doesn't work just keep trying.