# How does a miner determine the sequence of transactions?

Tags: blockchain, mining

Let's say I have a first-come-first-serve bounty contract. Whoever calls "getBounty()" first gets all balance owned by the contract.

Now if 10 people create transactions calling the getBounty() function - How does the blockchain/the miner determine who comes first and gets the ethers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several related questions like [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2856/what-happens-when-a-smart-contract-gets-several-similar-calls-in-the-same-block?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/what-is-the-default-ordering-of-transactions-during-mining-in-e-g-geth). IMHO, all the answers lead to "it's arbitrary".

Maybe you can make a central interface to your contract in order to further control the ordering of the transactions. You can also design your contract in such a way that it does not accept multiple transactions in a single block.

To implement this, you can store the "last" block in a global variable and update it like this:

```
contract C {
    uint lastBlock = 0;

    function myFunction(){
        if(block.number>lastBlock){
            lastBlock = block.number; // update lastBlock
        } else if (block.number == lastBlock){
            throw; // don't allow if this block already had a transaction
        }
        // do what the function is supposed to do here
    }
}
```

Comment: "You can also design your contract in such a way that it does not accept multiple transactions in a single block."

Thats interesting. Could you elaborate a bit more how this could be approached?

Comment: @TripleSpeeder added an example.