# How can a miner mine their own ethereum transaction?

Tags: transactions, mining

From the answer of this question [Can miners mine their own transactions?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12281/can-miners-mine-their-own-transactions) it seems that if someone wanted to make a transaction on the ethereum blockchain for the smallest transaction price (gas) possible, they could run a miner to mine the specific transaction. My question is: How can this be done? (the necessary steps)

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned in the answer to the post you've referenced, putting your own transactions into a block doesn't make that block easier to mine. You'd still be competing against the rest of the miners, who may or may not have included your low-priced transaction in the block they're mining. You'd probably<sup>1</sup> be better off broadcasting the transaction and hoping someone else - perhaps with far greater hashing power than you - picks it up. (i.e. Use the power of the rest of the network rather than cutting yourself off from it.)

To actually answer your question though, there are a couple of options I can think of. (Other people may have other ideas.)

1. If you're using the Parity client, use the `--tx-queue-strategy` flag to prioritise low priced transactions. (Though this won't guarantee yours is included if the transaction pool is full of cheap transactions.) I think the same can be done with the `--gasprice` option. Geth doesn't have a way to set maximum limits for gas price, only minimum limits, so you can't prioritise low prices.
2. The only way I can see to guarantee that your own transactions are prioritised is to edit the code. For Geth, I've mentioned where transactions from the memory pool are sorted in [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/6111/52) previous answer. You'd need to inspect the `from` address in each transaction, and only add to the block you're mining if the address is yours. (I think. There might be an easier way of creating a local transaction pool containing only your transactions, but that would need some digging and design.)

<sup>1</sup> I've no way of quantifying this...

Comment: I _think_ you can quantify the benefit of broadcasting the transaction fairly easily. Using a gas price estimator, you can estimate how many blocks it will take for your transaction to be included at the price you want; call this x. Then you find out what your expected time, in blocks, to mine a block is (using, for example, a mining calculator); call this y. Then you look at the ratio of x to y. No? Of course, you pay the low fee to someone else rather than spend nothing because you paid yourself (at the expense, perhaps, of getting an uncle block or something).

Comment: @RichardHorrocks thank you for this answer. Can you please go into a little detail about where and how you'd add the criteria to only accept TXs from a certain address?