# How do miners choose what transactions to include first in the block (after London)?

Tags: web3js, gas, mining, gas-price, blocks

I have read [Does using a very high gas limit somehow get your transactions executed slower?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/76543/does-using-a-very-high-gas-limit-somehow-get-your-transactions-executed-slower) and [How transactions are selected by the miners?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/80361/how-transactions-are-selected-by-the-miners)

My main question is the same, how do miners include transactions in a block, is this still based on gasPrice * gasLimit, or did this change after the London fork/EIP-1559?