# How to retrieve ERC20 from a hacked address monitored by a bot?

Tags: gas, gas-price, blocks

Check it out: https://discordapp.com/channels/554623348622098432/633092550407749652/714325610050355260

[image]

The address that was hacked: https://etherscan.io/address/0x1b3e1786c3f8524ca0f3175b0b37bcc1bee5a6d5

There are still some ERC20 left, probably the hacker did not account for all the tokens.

I was thinking that I can send 2 transactions in a single block:

1. Send small portion of ETH
2. Use that ETH to pay for the gas and send the ERC20 to my white hack address

Tried looking up how the transaction ordering works: [What is the default ordering of transactions during mining, in e.g. geth?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/what-is-the-default-ordering-of-transactions-during-mining-in-e-g-geth)

**Is the 1 + 2 plan possible?**

- I can surely generate raw TX with high gas prices and submit simultaneously, hopefully 1 will be higher up in the same block than 2?
- Or maybe order of the transactions in the block does not matter?
- Or maybe even if transaction 2 gets mined in the next block, it will be still faster than the attacker?

Answer (score 4):

I think your situation is pretty similar, so you may try a method described in this article: https://medium.com/mycrypto/operation-cryptokitty-rescue-93fd8e00e4f8