# State Changes within a Block

Tags: transactions, mining, blocks

I read somewhere that the 'state' is only updated at the end of each block. I've also read that each block contains a specific sequence of transactions, and thus implicitly 'updates' the state within a block. This might be semantics, but I just want to be certain about how state variables are updated: will a transaction that alters the state do so before the next transaction, regardless of whether it is in the same block?

To be clear: assume a contract variable `Book` is 10 ETH, so that users can take bets against this 10 ETH. Each time a transaction bets an amount `X`, `Book` is decreased by `X`: `Book = Book - X`. Bets are restricted so that `Book`>=0 at all times: `require(Book - X >= 0)` at the top of the betting function.  If Bob bets 6 ETH, and Alice bets 6 ETH, this would obviously be counter to my requirement. However, if their transactions are in the same block, would the second transaction be rejected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will a transaction that alters the state do so before the next transaction, regardless of whether it is in the same block?

**Yes**

> if their transactions are in the same block, would the second transaction be rejected?

**Yes**

An important point is that neither Alice or Bob knows who is first: the miner decides which transaction is first.

See also [What is the default ordering of transactions during mining?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/what-is-the-default-ordering-of-transactions-during-mining-in-e-g-geth)

Comment: I thought so, but that's reassuring.